# Updating Expired .p12 certificate in Mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

My application sends notification the .p12 certificate expiring soon so do we need to send the application again to Apple store ?

If not then we just create wlapp file with new .p12 certificate and deploy on our Mobilefirst server or we need to do more configuration ?

Please advice ?

Answer (score 0):

> My application sends notification the .p12 certificate expiring soon so do we need to send the application again to Apple store ?

No.

> If not then we just create wlapp file with new .p12 certificate and deploy on our Mobilefirst server?

You could replace the certificate in the project and re-build it so an updated .wlapp file is created, and then deploy this .wlapp file to the MobileFirst Server.

Alternatively, instead of rebuilding the application, you call also call a server endpoint to update only the certificate. See here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/r_restapi_apns_credentials_put.html

Comment: Thanks Idan, I tried same but getting following error  Connection to APNS closed. Delivery error: INVALID_TOKEN, error code: 8, identifier: 3.[10/24/16 13:58:28:523 GST] 000c9fbe ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection E FPWSE1083E: Failed to send APNS notification with identifier 3, device token