# Connection to APNS closed. Delivery error: INVALID_TOKEN

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

[After updating .p12 file and deployed .wlapp on mobilefirst server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099612/updating-expired-p12-certificate-in-mobilefirst), push notification has stopped working and getting following error:

> Connection to APNS closed. Delivery error: INVALID_TOKEN, error code: 8, identifier: 1.
>   [ERROR   ] FPWSE1083E: Failed to send APNS notification with identifier 1, device token.

please advice, what we are doing wrong. is this related to .p12 file or do we need to send our application to apple store?

Secondly we notice that after updating .p12 file client gets the direct update ,so is this normal behavior?

Comment: Idan, Your answer with previous post was clear but after updating wlapp file we faced the issue mentioned above and also client device got direct update, please advice thanks in advance

Comment: The direct update upon wlapp deployment is IMO a bug and I've opened an internal defect to have it investigated. Feel free to open a PMR about this specific issue. I don't know yet about the other issue with push failing.

Answer (score 0):

The message - "Connection to APNS closed. Delivery error: INVALID_TOKEN, error code: 8, identifier: 1."

is a feedback from APNS.

This message comes from APNS normally when you have a development entitled certificate and you connect to production APN server or vice-versa (production entitled certificate and connecting to sandbox APN).

Comment: How does MF server decided what APNS server to send it to?

Comment: Based on the name of the certificate in MFP versions before 8.0. In 8.0 it uses the option you chose -sandbox or production